# Reduce noise by averaging images coming from x-ray camera (16 bit grayscale)

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, imaging

I am getting 16 bit grayscale images from a camera. I want to reduce the noise of these images by averaging the images (by factor of 2, 4 etc).

I have the pixel data in a byte array. I have tried to use Aforge.Net,but the code throws exception when trying to apply noise reduction (`AForge.Imaging.UnsupportedImageFormatException: 'Source pixel format is not supported by the filter.'`).

Is there a better way to apply noise reduction by averaging incoming images directly on a byte array?

Comment: This is called [Image Stacking](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+image+stacking+software) and is often used in astronomy.

Comment: are you looking for recommendations? that'd be off-topic. are you looking for help in debugging the exception? then your question needs a [mre]

Comment: Any image is a byte array in the end. You really need to be more specific. Are you working on DICOM images? (I would expect that from an x-Ray)

Comment: I'd probably use openCV, average images in a float format, and then convert back to 16bit if needed.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I am working with images coming from x-ray camera. These are 16 bit gray scale images. I need to apply noise reduction algorithm by taking average of these images (by overlapping 2 or 4 images). These images are later saved to DICOM file (if the user chooses to)

Comment: Averaging can be used to reduce noise in some images, but there are other techniques that might work better depending on the type of noise. If using a professional SDK is an option for you, try the noise-reduction features of [LEADTOOLS SDKs](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/to/removing-noise.html). Almost all SDK functions work with different image types, including 16-bit grayscale. If you'd like to try it, you can download a free evaluation edition [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).